# Error when using defaultdict in python. I am new to python , i am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/py

from collections import defaultdict
"i am getting str object has no attribute appened"
class car:

    def __init__(self,car_name):

    self.car_name = car_name


class model(car):

    def __init__(self,car_model,car_name):

    self.car_model=car_model

    car.__init__(self,car_name)

cars1=defaultdict(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    i=1

    while(i<=2):

        car_name=raw_input("Enter the car name: ")

        car_model=raw_input("Enter the car model: ")

        brand=model(car_model,car_name)

        if brand.car_name in cars1:

            print "1"

            print brand.car_name

#### here i am getting this error ######

            cars1[brand.car_name].append(brand.car_model)

        else:

            print "2"

            cars1[brand.car_name]=brand.car_model

            i+=1

    for key,values in cars1.items():

        print key+":"+values

        print cars1.items()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' in tis code. I am trying to use default dict and checking if the key is already present , i am using append option. In that i am getting that error

Comment: The values in the dictionary are strings (`cars1[brand.car_name] = brand.car_model)`. Why do you expect `cars1[some_key].append` to work?

Comment: I want two values for same key

Comment: @ DeepSpace , I want two values for same key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because in case the key does not exist you insert a string as the value (`cars1[brand.car_name] = brand.car_model`).

Since you are using `defaultdict` you don't even need to perform this check, just call `append`. If the key doesn't exist an empty list will be created, that's the point of using a `defaultdict`.

```
brand = model(car_model, car_name)

cars1[brand.car_name].append(brand.car_model)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood. Please correct me if i am wrong. When using cars1[brand.car_name] = brand.car_model , it will not create an list. even though it is a default dict. SO we should use only  ars1[brand.car_name].append(brand.car_model)

Comment: @AADHIA.R The callable that is passed it to `defaultdict` is called only when a key is missing.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please give me some detailed answer. I am new to python that is why?